# error creating 2d array of type object

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, 2d

So, I'm trying to make a board that holds objects called Nodes but for some reason, when I try to create the array of Nodes, I get the error in the title but don't understand why. From everything I've learned,

"public static Node[][] board = new Node[11][11];"

should be a valid statement. All I want to do here is make an array that's 11x11. I fill the array in a loop later.

I've looked for help on here and elsewhere but can't find anything to solve the problem. Some ideas are close but the problem still persists. Any help would be great.

```
public class Board {

    //creates the board
    public static Node[][] board = new Node[11][11];

    //create an empty node and place it in  every other location
    //like a checkered board.
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j< board[i].length; j+=2) {
            if(i%2 == 0) {//if it is an even row start at 0
                board[i][j] = new Node(null);
            }else if(j+1 < board[i].length){//if odd row and less than length, start at 1
                board[i][j+1] = new Node(false);
            }else{
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: If this is Java, you might add the `java` tag.

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: your code cannot be compiled so hard to say what is your problem

Comment: I forgot to put it in a method or constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a method or constructor, I don't believe Java lets you put statements in the class body.

```
public class Board {

    // Creates the board
    public static Node[][] board = new Node[11][11];

    public Board() {
        // Create an empty node and place it in  every other location
        // like a checkered board.
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j< board[i].length; j+=2) {
                if(i%2 == 0) {
                    // Even row start at 0
                    board[i][j] = new Node(null);
                }
                else if(j+1 < board[i].length) {
                    // Odd row and less than length, start at 1
                    board[i][j+1] = new Node(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```